# How to improve type-safety for String- or Double-based values?

Tags: scala

I'm wondering the best way to achieve type-safety with my code when various values might all be `String`s or `Double`s, but are still incompatible.  For example, I might have units in pounds and kilograms, but I should be forbidden to assign one to the other.  Likewise, I might have a person ID as a `String` and a lookup table of animal IDs as a `Map[String,Int]`, but I should be forbidden to look a person up in the animals table.

Conceptually I'm looking for something like this:

```
class PersonId extends String
class AnimalId extends String

var p : PersonId = "1234"
var tab : Map[AnimalId,Int] = Map("foo" -> 5, "bar" -> 6)
tab.get(p)  // Want this to cause a compile error
```

But there are several problems making that not work.  Suggestions for something that fits the spirit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot extend `String` for obvious reasons. I suggest using case classes for that:

```
case class PersonId(id:String)
case class AnimalId(id:String)
```

Syntax gets a little bit more complicated, but not that much. And you can use case classes easily when pattern matching!

```
var p: PersonId = PersonId("1234")
var tab: Map[AnimalId,Int] = Map(AnimalId("foo") -> 5, AnimalId("bar") -> 6)
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd use [value classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) for this. It behaves pretty much the same as a regular case class but the compiler places some restrictions on it, and generally it never has to actually waste time/memory creating the wrapper object - it can usually use the underlying value directly.

```
case class Person(value: String) extends AnyVal
case class Animal(value: String) extends AnyVal
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution is just use

```
case class PersonId(id:String)
case class AnimalId(id:String)
```

This solution is usually good enough.

If you want to play a bit with Scala's type system you can do something like that -

```
  trait Person

  trait Animal

  case class IdOf[T](s: String) extends AnyVal

  implicit def string2idOf[T](s: String): IdOf[T] = IdOf(s)

  var p: IdOf[Person] = "1234"
  var tab: Map[IdOf[Animal], Int] = Map(("foo": IdOf[Animal]) -> 5, ("bar": IdOf[Animal]) -> 6)
  tab.get(p) 
// Error:(25, 11) type mismatch;
// found   : com.novak.Program.IdOf[com.novak.Program.Person]
// required: com.novak.Program.IdOf[com.novak.Program.Animal]
// tab.get(p)
      ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option is Scalaz's [tagged type](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Tagged+type.html). Might be useful in [some cases](http://etorreborre.blogspot.com/2011/11/practical-uses-for-unboxed-tagged-types.html) as it alows you to combine your type with some other type without creating new instance of this other type (value classes do simmilar for primitive types); however new Scalaz requires to explicitly unbox it (with `Tag.unwrap`), so not much useful as one can expect.

Example:

```
trait Person
val Person = Tag.of[Person]
val person = Prsn("Me")
Person.unwrap(person)
trait Animal
val Animal = Tag.of[Animal]
val animal = Anml("Me")
Animal.unwrap(person) //error
Animal.unwrap(animal)
```

Just quotes:

> Suppose we want a way to express mass using kilogram, because kg is
>   the international standard of unit. Normally we would pass in Double
>   and call it a day, but we can’t distinguish that from other Double
>   values. Can we use case class for this?
>
> ```
> case class KiloGram(value: Double)
> ```
>
> Although it does adds type safety,
>   it’s not fun to use because we have to call x.value every time we need
>   to extract the value out of it. Tagged type to the rescue.
>
> ```
> scala> sealed trait KiloGram defined trait KiloGram
>
> scala> def KiloGram[A](a: A): A @@ KiloGram = Tag[A, KiloGram](a)
> KiloGram: [A](a: A)scalaz.@@[A,KiloGram]
>
> scala> val mass = KiloGram(20.0) mass: scalaz.@@[Double,KiloGram] =
> 20.0
>
> scala> sealed trait JoulePerKiloGram
> defined trait JoulePerKiloGram
>
> scala> def JoulePerKiloGram[A](a: A): A @@ JoulePerKiloGram = Tag[A, JoulePerKiloGram](a)
> JoulePerKiloGram: [A](a: A)scalaz.@@[A,JoulePerKiloGram]
>
> scala> def energyR(m: Double @@ KiloGram): Double @@ JoulePerKiloGram =
>          JoulePerKiloGram(299792458.0 * 299792458.0 * Tag.unsubst[Double, Id, KiloGram](m))
> energyR: (m: scalaz.@@[Double,KiloGram])scalaz.@@[Double,JoulePerKiloGram]
>
> scala> energyR(mass)
> res4: scalaz.@@[Double,JoulePerKiloGram] = 1.79751035747363533E18
>
> scala> energyR(10.0)
> <console>:18: error: type mismatch;
>  found   : Double(10.0)
>  required: scalaz.@@[Double,KiloGram]
>     (which expands to)  AnyRef{type Tag = KiloGram; type Self = Double}
>               energyR(10.0)
>                       ^
> ```